# Show that $q \equiv 1 \mod p$...

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The problem:

> If $p$ is a prime and $q(\neq 2)$ is a prime divisor of $2^p-1$, then 
>   $$q \equiv 1 \mod p$$

Sorry about deleting my other work guys. I messed up when trying to re-post. My original question/confusion was in regards to how to come to the conclusion that $p|q-1$. This was apparent in the work I had show in my first attempt at a proof and in what my Edit 1 (neither exist because I messed up with posting Edit 2). I hadn't thought to apply Fermat's Theorem to $q$, instead applying it to $2^p$. This caused heavy confusion on my end. Once apply Fermat's Theorem to q, at the suggestion of Daniel Fischer, I came closer, but still made my way down the wrong road. Finally, Daniel brought up the idea of multiplicative order. I was still confused, and he ended showing how to work properly with the order. With this, I have (hopefully) my final proof.

**EDIT 2**:
Thanks to Daniel Fischer, again, this should be it:

> **Proof**
>
> Since $q|(2^p-1)$, we have
>   $$2^p \equiv 1 \mod q$$
>   Recalling Fermat's Little Theorem, let $a=2$. Then it follows that since q is prime,
>   $$2^{q-1} \equiv 1 \mod q$$
>   Now recall the definition of finite multiplicative order. If we have a fixed integer, say a, such that $[a]^k_n \equiv [1]_n$, we say that the the *order of $a$ modulo $n$* (we will denote it $\mathbb{ord}_n(a)$) is $k$ where k is the smallest integer for which we produce $[1]_n$
>
> For our problem, we have $\mathbb{ord}_q(2)$ since 
>   $$2^p \equiv 1 \mod q$$
>   $$2^{q-1} \equiv 1 \mod q$$
>   It follows that $\mathbb{ord}_q(2)|q-1$ and $\mathbb{ord}_q(2)|p$. Since $p$ is prime, we know by definition of prime that $p|p$ or $1|p$, so since $\mathbb{ord}_q(2)|p$, $\mathbb{ord}_q(2)=p$ or $\mathbb{ord}_q(2)=1$.
>
> If $\mathbb{ord}_q(2)=1$, then that would mean that 
>   $$2 \equiv 1 \mod q \implies 1 \equiv 0 \mod q \implies q|1$$
>   But we know that $q$>2 is a prime, so this is impossible. Thus, $\mathbb{ord}_q(2)$ must be p. It follows then that
>   $$\mathbb{ord}_q(2)|q-1$$
>   $$\implies p|q-1$$
>   $$\implies q \equiv 1 \mod p$$
>
> $Q.E.D$

Comment: Fermat's theorem is good, but you focused on the wrong prime.

Comment: But...how would I apply Fermat's theorem to q? I can't just say
$q^p \equiv q \mod p$ can I?

Comment: You know that $2^{q-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{q}$, so ...

Comment: Oh whoa! Since q is prime that is absolutely true! I'm going to post an edit. If you can, please let me know if my deduction is legitimate.

Comment: No, $q-1 = p$ need not hold. For example $2^{11}-1 = 23\cdot 89$. What do you know about the order of $2$ modulo $q$?

Comment: The mistake in your solution is subtle. The problem is that actually, $2^{q-1}=q\beta+1$, but we cannot necessarily colclude that $\alpha=\beta$. As Daniel suggested, the usual proof requires a new concept, the _order_ of $2$ modulo some number.

Comment: Hmm...well we know that the order is the smallest $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t for fixed $a \in \mathbb{Z}$,
$[a]_n^k=[1]_n$.

For our problem, since $[2]_q^{q-1} = [1]_q$ and $[2]_q^p = [1]_q$, then the the orders are equal for $2$ modulo $q$? I'm not quite sure...

Comment: a) $2^{q-1}\equiv 1 \pmod{q}$ implies that the order of $2$ divides $q-1$. b) $2^p \equiv 1 \pmod{q}$ implies that the order divides $p$. Since $p$ is prime, that means the order is either $1$ or $p$. It cannot be $1$, since $2^1-1 = 1$ is not divisible by $q$.

Comment: Daniel, thank you. I didn't know this about the multiplicative order. You've been a tremendous help.

Comment: You are saying that $2^{q-1} = 2^p$ that often is not true under the set of hypothesis of your problem. For instance, let $p = 11$, then $2^p -1 = 2047 = 23·89$. Then $q$ can be $23$ or $89$ and neither satisfy that $q-1 = p$.